# Android SDK parsing SMS

Tags: android, parsing, sms

I need parse sms messages. I have found a library https://github.com/adorsys/sms-parser-android. 
It is very comfortable, because I can divide message and indicate phone number. 
But, it does not work. 
I write BEGIN /* message */ END and an application tells me “No Number” and “No message”.
I send message from emulator to emulator. 
Android shows me the number (555) 521-5556. I tried to write “5215556”, “521-5556”, “5555215556”, “5215556”. The application does not work. 
  What can I do? I set library in Gradle. I do not touch Manifest, how author in the example.

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="com.example.kostya.testsms">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

        </application>

    </manifest>

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @NonNull
    private TextView smsSenderTextView;
    @NonNull
    private TextView smsMessageTextView;
    @NonNull
    private LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager;

    private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("AAA", "test");
            if (intent.getAction().equals(SmsReceiver.INTENT_ACTION_SMS)) {

                String receivedSender = intent.getStringExtra(SmsReceiver.KEY_SMS_SENDER);
                String receivedMessage = intent.getStringExtra(SmsReceiver.KEY_SMS_MESSAGE);
                smsSenderTextView.setText(getString(R.string.text_sms_sender_number,
                        receivedSender != null ? receivedSender : "NO NUMBER"));
                smsMessageTextView.setText(getString(R.string.text_sms_message,
                        receivedMessage != null ? receivedMessage : "NO MESSAGE"));
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
        if (requestCode == SmsTool.REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS
                && (grantResults.length <= 0
                || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.warning_permission_not_granted),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SmsConfig.INSTANCE.initializeSmsConfig(
                "BEGIN",
                "END",
                "5555215556");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            SmsTool.requestSMSPermission(this);
        }

        initViews();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        unRegisterReceiver();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver();
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        smsSenderTextView = findViewById(R.id.sms_sender_text_view);
        smsMessageTextView = findViewById(R.id.sms_message_text_view);

        smsSenderTextView.setText(getString(R.string.text_sms_sender_number, ""));
        smsMessageTextView.setText(getString(R.string.text_sms_message, ""));
    }

    private void registerReceiver() {
        localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(SmsReceiver.INTENT_ACTION_SMS);
        localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    private void unRegisterReceiver() {
        localBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

And it is screen emulators...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgtp1.png)

I gave permission...

Comment: Why not ask the author?

Comment: I don't know  =( 
I did not think about it

Comment: How can I find his email  ?

Comment: Wouldn't you ask here: https://github.com/adorsys/sms-parser-android/issues

Comment: @Константин could you please reformat your question to make it more readable?

Comment: What could I write ? I have used your example and it doesn't work =(. I want to specify format of nubmers. Maybe am I use wrong format ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm one of the authors of the library: I used the standard example, exchanged the begin and end keywords to match the ones you used

```
SmsConfig.INSTANCE.initializeSmsConfig(
            "BEGIN",
            "END",
            "5555215556");
```

And I used the same message you sent
[image]

and it works:
[image]

Have you correctly updated your Start and End Keywords?
Do the phone number in your emulator and the one you specify match?

Comment: I sorry that I take your time, but if I do how you, It works. If I set the application on my phone, i will get no message and no number =( 
The format of number my country is (375 XX XXX XX XX), I have written on this number in emulator and it works.

Comment: https://ibb.co/f9SSU8
https://ibb.co/djPkGo
I have tried +375295537011/295537011/5537011/00375295537011 and so on....

Comment: It's works! I am sorry, that I took your expensive time! I didn't specify sign "+"

Comment: And by the way, thanks for using this library! Have fun with it.